# Python import not working, even after creating __init__ in parent folders

Tags: python, package, python-import

Why isn't this `import` statement working, even after I created `__init__` in every folder?

[image: Import not working in Python]

I want to import `func1()` from `basepackage\package1\p1\p1py.py`. The root folder `basepackage` is located on my desktop.

```
import package1.p1.p1py
import basepackage.package1.p1.pipy as okay     '''this king of import statement is showing error'''
okay.func1()
package1.p1.p1py.func1()
```

The code above doesn't work, and throws the following error:

```
File "c:\Users\shiv\Desktop\basepackage\package1\p11\p11py.py", line 1, in <module>
import package1.p1.p1py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package1'
```

Comment: What is the folder structure of your project? Is this `c:\Users\shiv\Desktop\basepackage\package1\p11\p11py.py` the right path to your script?

Comment: `p11py.py` is the executing script, which appears to be importing `p1py.py`, a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

Within the package you need to use [relative imports](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports) rather than importing from the package name itself (that will only work if the package is already installed in your Python path).

For example, if I have a package set up like:

```
base
.
└── package1
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── p1
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── p1py.py
    └── p11
        ├── __init__.py
        └── p11py.py
```

and `p1py.py` contains:

```py
def func1():
    print("Hello!")
```

Then, if you wanted `p11py.py` to be able to use `func1`, then you could have it contain:

```py
# relative import from p1.p1py
from ..p1.p1py import func1

def func2():
    # use func1!
    func1()
```

Then, within the `base` directory, you can do:

```py
from package1.p11.p11py import func2

func2()
Hello!
```

See, e.g., [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time) for links to various other questions/answers about relative imports.